# How to push to another repository which is below to another tenant by CI

Tags: git, yaml, devops

How to push to another repository which is below to another tenant by CI?
We have to release code to our customers. They also use Azure devops. Is it possible to do it by CI?

Answer (score 0):

I used "Git mirror" to solve my problem. And I used PAT.

```
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml
trigger:
- master
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
steps:
- script: |
     cd /tmp && rm -rf /tmp/$(TmpRepoDir)
     git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)" clone --mirror $(Build.Repository.Uri) $(TmpRepoDir)
     git -C /tmp/$(TmpRepoDir) push --mirror https://{anything}:{PTA}/{organization}/{project name}/_git/{repository name}
  displayName: 'Copy to GitLab'
```